# $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k !}$ for each $S_n$ in terms of $n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

How can we compute

$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k !}$ for each $S_n$ in terms of $n$?

I tried to compute 2 items together but that didn't work for me. I also tried to find a recurrence relation between $n$ and $n-1$ but that also didn't work. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Find $S_1$ and inductively find $$S_n = S_{n-1} + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}$$ Not sure if that is what you want though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit as $n \to \infty$ is $1-\frac 1e$, which can be derived by looking at the series for $e^{-1}$.  I suspect you won't do better for finite sums than just adding them up.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives $S_n=1-\frac{\Gamma(n+1),-1)}{e\,\Gamma(n+1)}$. Now that I know how to find such value.